# Getting Service Port from Consul DNS Server

Tags: consul

I am using Consul for service discovery. Consul server is running on 192.168.61.10. I am having multiple services as follows: -
Service A - One Instance, Service B - Two Instances, on 192.168.61.125 at port 2222 and another at 192.168.61.126 at port 3333.

Both these services are in .NET Core 3.1 and I am using a nuget package `Consul 1.6.10.1` for Service Registration, Health Checks and Service De-Registartion. I don't want to add the address of target service in the configuration file of any service.

In a typical business use case, Service A is calling Service B. I am able to able to resolve my Service B as `serviceb.service.consul` and getting both the IP Addresses using Consul DNS Server.
Now for calling Service B I just want its port on which it is listening.
I found that there is a nuget package `DnsClient` which can give the complete `SRV` record in code and I can get the complete addresses for all the the instances of target service.

```
void QueryService()
{
    LookupClient lookUpClient = new LookupClient(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.61.10"), 8600);
    IDnsQueryResponse result = lookUpClient.Query("serviceb.service.consul", QueryType.SRV);
    var port = ((SrvRecord)result.Answers.First()).Port;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
      var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync($"http://serviceb.service.consul:{port}/weatherforecast");
      Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
     }
}
```

Now my question is that if I need to resolve this using code then all Load Balancing responsibility is on code itself, which I think is not correct. One solution of this is that I can use the default http/https ports (80 or 443) which solves my problem. But this will restrict me to run one service per VM. So is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application sends a query to Consul's DNS server, the server randomizes the set of service instances in the response for each query. If the total number of registered instances exceeds what can be sent in a UDP packet, the response will only contain a *subset* of the available service instance IPs. If [`enable_truncate`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#enable_truncate) is set to `true`, the truncated flag will be set on the response to signal more information can be provided if the query is retried with TCP.

For example, if you have 25 instances of service B registered in Consul, and your application queries Consul's DNS server using UDP, you may only receive information on 3-4 of those services instances in the response data for that given query. A subsequent DNS request will likely return a different set of IPs since the order is random. This randomization provides very simple load balancing of requests across upstream services.

You could modify your application so that it connects to a random instance from the randomized list of IPs in the DNS response, but that is probably redundant to what Consul is already providing if all you want to do is randomize connections across available upstream hosts.

Comment: Thanks Blake for this. Just one thing to confirm that this randomization behaviour of Consul Server is actually following which load balancer policy.

Comment: It does not follow a specific load balancer policy. It’s completely random. That is mostly sufficient to distribute requests across nodes. If you need more granular load balancing, retries, etc then I recommend taking a look at Consul’s service mesh features.